# nvidia-smi getting clocks_throttle_reasons.active bitmask into english?

Tags: bash, nvidia, nvidia-smi

This there a way to get the bitmask of the clocks_throttle_reasons.active into plain english? Is there perhaps a list somewhere? Please find my command below

```
nvidia-smi --query-gpu=clocks_throttle_reasons.active --format=csv
```

The above code returns the follow `0x0000000000000004` bitmask which looking at my data suggests that its a high power draw issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/nvml-api/group__nvmlClocksThrottleReasons.html ? It looks "good enough".

Comment: Thanks! i had overlooked that page for some reasons

Comment: *`looking at my data suggests that its a high power draw issue`*. Sounds like you already have a list explaining the meaning of these bitmasks. Is this question about *automatically* converting a bitmask into english according to this list?